# How to shuffle three variables in this code?

Tags: php, arrays, variables, automated-tests, shuffle

I have a little problem, I try to make an online test but I need to shuffle answare so
1 is good answare and 2,3 bad but all time appears a = 1 b = 2  c = 3 and i want something to randomize that like a=2 b=3 c=1 how i can do that?

Code is here:

```
$result = mysql_query( "SELECT * FROM questions ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,10");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $rows[] = $row;
    $question_id = $row['question_id'];
    $question = $row['question'];
    $answare_good = $row['answare_good'];
    $answare_badi = $row['answare_badi'];
    $answare_badii = $row['answare_badii'];
    $number += 1;
    echo '<tr>
    <td rowspan="3" width="10">'.$number.'</td>
    <td rowspan="3" width="70%"><p>'.$question.'</p></td>
    <td width="30%" height="33%"><input type="checkbox" name="a1" id="a1">
    '.$answare_good.'</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td width="30%" height="33%"><input type="checkbox" name="a2" id="a2">
    '.$answare_badi.'</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td  width="30%" height="33%"><input type="checkbox" name="a3" id="a3">
    '.$answare_badii.'</td>
    </tr>';
```

I try something to array shuffle $answare_good & $answare_badi & $answare_badii but i faill.

Comment: While `ORDER BY RAND()` does the work and *looks* nice, it actually is a bad trick: it does not scale. A better approach is to pick 10 random numbers and use that in your `LIMIT`.

Comment: If I didn't know better I would say that rowspan was an attribute devised by the devil!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this code:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM questions ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,10");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $rows[] = $row;
    $question_id = $row['question_id'];

    $answers = array(
        array('a1', 'val1', $row['answare_good']),
        array('a2', 'val2', $row['answare_badi']),
        array('a3', 'val3', $row['answare_badii']),
    );
    shuffle($answers);

    $number += 1;

    echo '<tr>
    <td rowspan="3" width="10">'.$number.'</td>
    <td rowspan="3" width="70%"><p>'.$row['question'].'</p></td></tr>';
    foreach($answers as $answer) {
        echo '<tr><td width="30%" height="33%"><input type="checkbox" name="'.$answer[0].'" id="'.$question_id.'-'.$answer[0].'" value="'.$answer[1].'" />'.$answer[2].'</td></tr>';
    }
}
```

You would have to specify the value for the checkbox also to be able to get the value of checked answer...

Also move to `PDO` or at least `mysqli_*` functions as `mysql_*` functions are deprecated now...

**EDIT:** Also think of using `radio` instead of `checkbox` - assuming user should pick up just one answer. If You want to let the user to pick up more than one (or all three answers), then `checkbox` is OK.

Comment: This is a much better solution than what I wrote, deleting my answer, and upvoting yours

Answer (score 1):

If you need to have the variables available you can do extract additionally to the shuffle

```
$answers = array(
 'opt1' => 'answer1',
 'opt2' => 'answer2',
 'opt3' => 'answer3'
);

shuffle($answers);
extract($answers);
```

// access the variables

```
echo $opt1;
echo $opt2;
echo $opt3;
```